# Is an element of an rvalue array (the element is obtained using subscript expression) an rvalue?

Tags: c++, arrays, rvalue

Consider this piece of code:

```
int a[]{0};
auto&& ref1 = std::move(a)[0];
auto&& ref2 = a[0];
```

If I understand the C++ standard (C++17) correctly, `ref1`'s type is `int&&` while `ref2`'s type is `int&` and that is the way it works in clang. However, in gcc and msvc both `ref1` and `ref2` are lvalue references.
Could somebody explain to me which behaviour (and why) is correct? Whichever option is the right one it seems that at least one of the compilers I mentioned has a bug.